# What's the difference between ∀a.∃b.L(b)→P(a) AND ∀a((∃b.L(b))→P(a)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Given that the following sentences are not logically equivalent, can you find an example structure in which one sentence comes out true while the other false? For instance, if L(x) indicates x > 5, and P(x) indicates x < 7 - what's the difference between the two phrases?

$\forall a.\exists b. (L(b) \to P(a))$

$\forall a.((\exists b.L(b)) \to P(a))$

At first look they both seem identical, but they actually aren't.

Comment: The first one says, for each $a$ you can find a $b$ such that $L(b)\implies P(a)$. The second one says, if for each $a$, there is a $b$ that makes $L(b)$ true then $P(a)$ is true.

Comment: Try rewriting the wffs using standard bracketing conventions. As they stand, neither is a sentence (well formed closed wff) in any syntax known to me.

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly this question was marked as off-topic, since I think Ido just doesn't know exactly how to pose the question--a pretty natural thing for someone who doesn't already understand the topic.  But with a little charity of interpretation, I think what would answer this question is to give an example structure in which one sentence comes out true while the other false, and a little explanation about how to read and think about a symbolic sentence like this.  The first sentence says "For all a, there is a b (such that ...)"

Comment: The second sentence says "For all a (if this then that)".  From this high-level description you can see how the sentences might mean two different things. In this particular example, because each predicate is one-place, it's a little hard to give a very convincing example. Using two-place predicates could give a more real-world sounding example.

Comment: For example, consider the sentence "For every person (a) there is a person (b) who, if (b) is the spouse of (a), then (a) is married."  This you could write as $\forall a. \exists b(S(b,a)\rightarrow M(a))$.  Notice that this sentence requires, for every person (a), the existence of a person (b).  That person (b) may be a spouse or not.  Contrast that with $\forall a((\exists b S(b,a))\rightarrow M(a))$.  This says, for each person (a), if that person has a spouse, then that person is married.  This sentence is more correct than the first.  Notice this sentence does not require anyone to exist

Comment: I noticed that you had used S(b,a) to find a logic connection between a and b. However, in the original sentences there weren't functions that took more than one parameter.
I'm looking for a more specific example. For instance, if L(x) indicates x > 5, and P(x) indicates x < 7 - what's the difference between them?